# Can you include HTML within PHP define()?

Tags: php, html

I want to know if it is possible to include HTML code within PHP `define()`.

I use `define()` for emailing purposes. I use it to send a verification email to users who register on the site. However, instead of a plain, old boring text, I want to know if it would be possible to include HTML elements, such as headers, images, etc..

Here's my current code:

```
define("EMAIL_VERIFICATION_CONTENT", "Activate your account by clicking the link below");
```

So the above code includes the email content with simply just text. I wish to add images, headers and colors into the email etc.

Any help or guidance would be great. Thank you!

Comment: what happened when you tested it?

Comment: Answer to your question: https://eval.in/519150

Comment: @chris85 what would of taken you less time, typing your test or asking this question ?

Comment: @chris85 That just shows the HTML tags, it doesn't actually style it?

Comment: for the love of peat just test it locally would ya.

Comment: @Dagon testing, but that just was just a it works example. I suspect(hope?) the OP actual has tested and is encountering some actual issue.

Comment: @Cwtch22 so you have HTML working and want it styled? If so, that is not a PHP question, it is an HTML/CSS question.

Comment: @chris85 No, HTML is not working on it.. It simply only shows the tags

Comment: Yea...on that page, in a browser it would display as is. In an email you need to send the header. Define your actual issue. There is not HTML in your actual question so it is hard to know what your are running into.

Comment: mail manual page example 4 - sending html email, bet a million dollars your missing the HTML headers or sending invalid html

Comment: Show the code that sends the email then. It might be escaping the HTML, or you might be sending your email as plaintext rather than `text/html`.

Comment: you should just accept Will's answer as that's the only question you actually asked and he is correct. If you have a new question relating to email, that should be posted as a new question, not tacked on in the comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely. It's just a string; test it out!

```
define("EMAIL_VERIFICATION_CONTENT", "<b>Activate your account</b> by clicking the link below");
```

That said, a `define()` might not be the best way to store strings for use in an HTML email. A better approach would be to put the emails in some type of template file, but that's outside the scope of this question.